# Firefox Headless Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

When running Firefox in headless mode with a Selenium test, I get the following error:

```
FirefoxHeadless WebDriver
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer
    Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
    System info: host: 'travis-job-925316c3-d616-45c0-b7bf-7d2d72059105', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-101-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    remote stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:172:5
    InvalidArgumentError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:299:5
    assert.that/<@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:385:13
    assert.integer@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:236:10
    assert.positiveInteger@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:254:3
    fromJSON@chrome://marionette/content/session.js:293:28
    match_@chrome://marionette/content/session.js:459:23
    fromJSON@chrome://marionette/content/session.js:428:12
    GeckoDriver.prototype.newSession@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:758:25
    despatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:560:20
    execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:534:11
    onPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:509:15
    onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:508:8
    _onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:500:9
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Google this error you'll get a lot of answers, but none provided a solution for me. The trick to solving this is to realise that the URLs in the stack trace can be typed into Firefox directly to view the source code.

[image]

In my case the important code from chrome://marionette/content/session.js is this:

```
case "manual":
if (typeof json.ftpProxy != "undefined") {
  [p.ftpProxy, p.ftpProxyPort] = fromHost("ftp", json.ftpProxy);
}
if (typeof json.httpProxy != "undefined") {
  [p.httpProxy, p.httpProxyPort] = fromHost("http", json.httpProxy);
}
if (typeof json.sslProxy != "undefined") {
  [p.sslProxy, p.sslProxyPort] = fromHost("https", json.sslProxy);
}
if (typeof json.socksProxy != "undefined") {
  [p.socksProxy, p.socksProxyPort] = fromHost("socks", json.socksProxy);
  p.socksVersion = assert.positiveInteger(json.socksVersion);
}
```

`p.socksVersion = assert.positiveInteger(json.socksVersion);` was the line of code that was failing, and from this I could work out that I needed to define the socks version property in the proxy settings.

```
final Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:" + myMainProxy.getPort());
proxy.setSslProxy("localhost:" + myMainProxy.getPort());
proxy.setSocksProxy("localhost:" + myMainProxy.getPort());
proxy.setSocksVersion(5); // This was missing before
proxy.setFtpProxy("localhost:" + myMainProxy.getPort());
```